# Embed JSON into JavaScript tests with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine

We currently have [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) tests for [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) running in our Ruby on Rails application. With that, we use [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) to generate API JSON files with fake data.

Would it be possible to embed those files into our JavaScript unit tests?

- We would prefer not to make Ajax calls to those files (performance)
- We try to avoid putting it into `assets` since it should be excluded in production code.

Our current structure looks like this:

**spec/controllerSpec.js**

```js
scope.user.handleUserLoaded({
  "is_logged_in": true,
  "preferred_name": "Christian"
});
expect(scope.user.isAuthenticated()).toBeTruthy();
```

**fixtures/fake_data/user.json**

```js
{
  "is_logged_in": true,
  "preferred_name": "Christian"
}
```

Instead of doing this duplication, we would prefer to have some kind of include into the JavaScript:

```js
scope.user.handleUserLoaded(<% include "fixtures/fake_data/user.json" %>);
expect(scope.user.isAuthenticated()).toBeTruthy();
```

What would be the best way to do this?
We can definitely move files around, use `.js.erb` files or try a different approach.

Comment: Why does it matter? Are you trying to enhance the performance of your unit tests? Do they take too long to run?

Comment: Are you running Jasmine external from Rails, or using [jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) or something similar? Jasminerice supports [JSON fixutres out of the box](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice#fixtures), or use [helper methods](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice#helper-methods) to do your own file loading.

Comment: @blesh we're trying to avoid duplication. In unit tests we also want to avoid making extra Ajax calls.

Comment: @BrandonTilley we currently use the `jasmine` gem, I'll look into Jasminerice a bit more.

Comment: " In unit tests we also want to avoid making extra Ajax calls." ... Why? Just curious.

Comment: @blesh indeed, that's for performance reasons

Comment: How long do your unit tests take? Have you considered just enabling caching for your unit test Ajax calls?

Comment: @blesh About a minute right now, caching is definitely an option, we're also looking at combining everything in one big JSON request upon load.

Comment: Ouch. Well, I'd try caching first, as it may have the best results-to-work ratio. Should be quick to implement, and it should speed things up quite a bit (after the first test, that is)